# Evitar que o interpretador de comando CMD use os operadores passados via parâmetro/argumento?

Tags: c#, c, c++, windows, cmd

Existe forma de evitar que os operadores presentes nos argumentos passados, via linha de comando, sejam **utilizados/interpretados** pelo interpretador **CMD** em **C, C++ ou C#**?

Quero fazer uso de caracteres presentes no argumento, independente de serem **operadores** ou não, mas não quero que o interpretador os intercepte e os utilize, especificamente estes **caracteres/operadores**:

**`&  &&  |  ||  <  >  >> e <<`**

Sendo que meu executável, ao receber esses caracteres, os trate como, de fato, caracteres. Não permitindo ao interpretador manipular a operação atribuída a esses caracteres, como operadores que são.

Em outras palavras...

Como passar parâmetros contendo os caracteres especiais  **`&, &&, |, ||, <, >, >>, e <<`** via linha de comando para a função main de uma aplicação de console feita em C#, mas, evitando que o CMD use esses parâmetros como operadores.

• **Obs.:** Sem usar prévio/edição/tratamento de **strings/operador** para posterior uso como **argumento/parametro**

É possível? Se é, como fazê-lo?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93783/discussion-on-question-by-it-wasnt-me-evitar-que-o-interpretador-de-comando-cmd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

̶N̶ã̶o̶ ̶s̶e̶i̶ ̶s̶e̶ ̶v̶a̶i̶ ̶l̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶e̶r̶v̶i̶r̶ ̶m̶a̶s̶ ̶e̶m̶ ̶*̶c̶#̶*̶ ̶o̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶ ̶d̶á̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶a̶ ̶f̶a̶z̶e̶r̶ ̶é̶ ̶c̶r̶i̶a̶r̶ ̶u̶m̶ ̶s̶h̶e̶l̶l̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶o̶(̶F̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶S̶h̶e̶l̶l̶)̶ ̶o̶n̶d̶e̶ ̶o̶ ̶u̶s̶u̶á̶r̶i̶o̶ ̶d̶i̶g̶i̶t̶a̶ ̶a̶ ̶l̶i̶n̶h̶a̶ ̶d̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶a̶n̶d̶o̶ ̶e̶n̶q̶u̶a̶n̶t̶o̶ ̶o̶ ̶f̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶s̶h̶e̶l̶l̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶c̶e̶s̶s̶a̶ ̶e̶s̶s̶a̶ ̶e̶n̶t̶r̶a̶d̶a̶ ̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶m̶i̶t̶e̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶a̶ ̶o̶ ̶`̶c̶m̶d̶`̶ ̶o̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶ ̶v̶o̶c̶ê̶ ̶q̶u̶i̶s̶e̶r̶.̶
̶
̶N̶e̶s̶s̶e̶ ̶e̶x̶e̶m̶p̶l̶o̶ ̶e̶u̶ ̶a̶p̶e̶n̶a̶s̶ ̶r̶e̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶m̶i̶t̶o̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶a̶ ̶o̶ ̶`̶c̶m̶d̶`̶ ̶e̶x̶a̶t̶a̶m̶e̶n̶t̶e̶ ̶t̶u̶d̶o̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶ ̶u̶s̶u̶á̶r̶i̶o̶ ̶d̶i̶g̶i̶t̶a̶r̶,̶ ̶ú̶n̶i̶c̶a̶ ̶c̶o̶i̶s̶a̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶ ̶f̶a̶ç̶o̶ ̶e̶n̶t̶r̶e̶ ̶o̶ ̶d̶i̶g̶i̶t̶a̶r̶ ̶d̶a̶ ̶l̶i̶n̶h̶a̶ ̶d̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶a̶n̶d̶o̶ ̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶c̶o̶n̶h̶e̶c̶i̶m̶e̶n̶t̶o̶ ̶p̶e̶l̶o̶ ̶`̶c̶m̶d̶`̶ ̶é̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶b̶r̶a̶r̶ ̶a̶ ̶l̶i̶n̶h̶a̶ ̶d̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶a̶n̶d̶o̶ ̶e̶m̶ ̶e̶s̶p̶a̶ç̶o̶s̶ ̶e̶ ̶i̶m̶p̶r̶i̶m̶i̶r̶ ̶s̶e̶u̶s̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶o̶n̶e̶n̶t̶e̶s̶ ̶e̶n̶t̶r̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶l̶c̶h̶e̶t̶e̶s̶:̶
̶

Para resolver seu problema eu criei um FakeShell que atua em dois modos. Modo DOS e Modo FakeShell.

**O que são esses dois modos?**

No modo DOS o programa funciona exatamente da mesma forma que o `CDM` os caracteres de operadores `&  &&  |  ||  <  >  >> e <<` são processados de forma tradicional realizando suas respectivas funções.

No modo FakeShell a linha de comando é interceptada e quebrada pela função [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) hospedada na `dll Shell32.dll`que faz a analise léxica da linha de comando segundo o padrão DOS, isso para que não haja problemas de fraturas ou incongruências com os argumentos. A quebra da linha de comando é passada para um vetor de strings, `string[] args = SplitArgs(cmd);`, onde o primeiro elemento é o nome do programa que você quer chamar e resto do vetor são os argumentos.

Então ao invés de usar o `CMD`, o programa cria um processo paralelo que chama o programa passado em `args[0]` utilizando o resto do vetor `args` como argumentos. O resultado é que os caracteres de operadores `&  &&  |  ||  <  >  >> e <<` não são processados deixam de serem entendidos como comandos e passam a ser compreendidos como simples strings.

**Por que dois modos?**

Porque o Modo FakeShell não funciona sob ambiente CMD então os comandos do DOS estão desabilitado e a única coisa que dá para fazer é chamar executáveis, arquivos de lote ou arquivos associados a aplicativos. Então o modo DOS serve para navegar no sistema e o modo FakeShell serve para ignorar comandos DOS.

**Como trocar os modos de operação?**
Pressione [CTRL] + P e depois enter.

O programa começa em modo DOS.

O código:

**EDITADO**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Linq;

namespace FakeShell
{
    class FakeShell
    {
        private static StringBuilder fakeOutput = null;




        //*********************************************************************************************************************
        //                                       EDIÇÃO
        //*********************************************************************************************************************
        private static bool prompt = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Usa a função Win32 CommandLineToArgvW para analisar e quebrar a string de entrada segundo o formato pedido pelos DOS
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entrada">String a ser analizada</param>
        /// <returns>Retorna a quebra da enrada em vetor de strings segundo a sintaxe do dos</returns>
        static string[] SplitArgs(string entrada)
        {
            int contador;
            IntPtr ptrArgumentos;
            string[] argumentos;

            ptrArgumentos = CommandLineToArgvW(entrada, out contador);
            if (ptrArgumentos == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return new string[] {"Erro a analisar o argumento"};                
            }
            try
            {
                argumentos = new string[contador];
                for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++)
                    argumentos[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(
                        Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptrArgumentos, i * IntPtr.Size));
                return argumentos;
            }
            finally
            {
                LocalFree(ptrArgumentos);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CommandLineToArgvW(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpCmdLine,
            out int pNumArgs);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr hMem);



        private static void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess,
            DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        {

            //Modifiquei o código despejo do buffer mas tem ainda um bug
            //Não sei o porque de em alguns momentos ele adiciona um \n na frente do prompt 
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(outLine.Data))
            {
                if (prompt)
                {
                    Console.Write(outLine.Data);
                    prompt = false;
                } else Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
            }
        }


        //*********************************************************************************************************************
        //                                       FIM - EDIÇÃO
        //*********************************************************************************************************************


        static void Main()
        {
            //****************************************************************************
            //                                       EDIÇÃO
            //****************************************************************************

            //Adicionei essa variável para controlar o processamento ou não do CMD. 
            //True é modo DOS
            //False é modo FakeShell
            bool processarCMD = true; //Começa em modo DOS
            //Adicionei essa variável para controlar e exibição ou não do prompt
            prompt = false;


            //*********************************************************************************************************************
            //                                       FIM - EDIÇÃO
            //*********************************************************************************************************************

            try
            {
                Process fakeShell = new Process();
                fakeShell.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                fakeShell.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                fakeShell.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                fakeShell.OutputDataReceived += OutputHandler;
                fakeShell.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                fakeShell.Start();
                StreamWriter streamWriter = fakeShell.StandardInput;
                fakeShell.BeginOutputReadLine();
                String cmd;
                Console.WriteLine("-Fake Shell- digite um comando ou pressione enter para saír:\n");
                Console.WriteLine("pressione [CTRL] + P para ativar/desativar o modo de processameto CDM");
                streamWriter.Flush();
                do
                {
                    //para pegar o prompt
                    prompt = true;
                    streamWriter.WriteLine("\x0D"); 

                    cmd = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmd))
                    {
                        //****************************************************************************
                        //                                       EDIÇÃO
                        //****************************************************************************

                        if (cmd == "\u0010")
                        {
                            processarCMD = !processarCMD;
                            Console.WriteLine("<<Modo " + ((processarCMD)? "DOS" : "FakeShell") + ">>\n");
                            continue;
                        }

                        //SplitArgs quebra a linha de comando inserida segundo o formato DOS
                        string[] args = SplitArgs(cmd);

                        //Caso queira comutar entre modo DOS e modo FakeShell pressione [CTRL] + P
                        if (processarCMD) streamWriter.WriteLine(cmd);
                        else
                        {
                            //Esse foreach é só um exemplo ele pega a quebra da linha de comando e imprime
                            //verticalmente entre colchetes só para mostrar sequencia de quebra.
                            foreach (var arg in args)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("[" + arg + "]");
                            }

                            //Cria um novo processo paralelo para executar seu Aplicativo
                            Process newProcess = new Process();


                            newProcess.StartInfo.FileName = args[0];





                            //Junta os argumentos  
                            newProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Join(" ", args.Skip(1).ToArray());


                            newProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;




                            //Inicializa o processo chamando o executável em outra janela
                            try
                            {
                                newProcess.Start();

                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                streamWriter.WriteLine(e.Message);

                                continue;
                            }
                            //Aguarda até que o applicativo esteja ecerrado
                            newProcess.WaitForExit();



                            //Fecha o processo paralelo
                            newProcess.Close();


                        }                     


                        //****************************************************************************
                        //                                   FIM - EDIÇÃO
                        //****************************************************************************
                    }
                } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmd));
                streamWriter.Close();
                fakeShell.WaitForExit();
                fakeShell.Close();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para fazer o teste criei um diretório e nesse diretório dei o seguinte nos dois modos:

C:\Teste>  CMD.exe /? >> Teste.txt

Esse comando chama a ajuda do CMD, que é extensa, e salva num arquivo chamado `Teste.txt` no modo DOS ele cria o arquivo normalmente no modo fake shell ele abre uma nova janela com o CMD e consome as srings `>>` e  `Teste.txt` como se fossem parâmetros e as ignora já a string `/?` também é consumida como parâmetro e na janela que foi aberta exibe a ajuda do CMD sem criar o arquivo `Teste.txt`.

OBS:
Para o seu programa C# consumir alinha de comando o método `Main` deve ter a seguinte assinatura:

[`static void Main(string[] args)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/)

Comment: Unindo o **`C#`** com o **`cmd`**: tenho o que me atende usando apenas um **`bat/cmd`** na chamada com os **`argumentos`** dessa forma: **`2>nul call_Redirect_Operator.cmd`**

Comment: Conteúdo do bat/cmd = linha chamando Redirect_Operator.exe:  **`@echo off && 2>nul Redirect_Operator.exe <nul & && > >> < << | || <nul`**

Comment: Sáida retorna dessa forma: **`@echo off && 2>nul Redirect_Operator.exe <nul & && > >> < << | || <nul`**  Daí, como fazer ele ignorar o que vem antes do nome e remover o 1º **`<nul`** (simula **`fake/enter`** no **`fakeshell`**) e o último **`<nul`**  ?

Comment: Para que retorne dessa **[forma:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwIV6.png)**

Comment: Deixa eu pensar pois ai analise da entrada é seletiva.

Comment: Esse código que eu escrevi não dá suporte para isso.

Comment: Importante é que entendas os comentário, igualmente, como foi chamado o bat, qual o comando dentro do bat e a observações dos comentários na imagem.

Comment: è muito próximo, ele n pode dar um "crop" no <nul da linha. ou tudo ante tudo antes do nome, tipo, n use/escreva, antes do nome, e p frente do nome remover 1ª e último <nul  ..

Comment: Eu entendi você quer algo tipo o $ do linux

Comment: isso,, é muito próximo..

Comment: Realmente eu vou ter que pensar a respeito. Me aguarde...

Comment: trankilo, sua resposta é a mais completa presente, e muito próximo do preciso, obrigado..Obs, o primeiro 2>nul pre nome, serve para não haver saida na "imersão"  do fake shell.. tipo, suprimir qualquer tela/mensagem do cmd...

Comment: Alguma informações para entendimento da interação **[`C#(programa) +bat/cmd(argumento/comandos/operadores) resultados desejado...`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2rcH.png)**

Comment: O problema que estou encontrando é seguinte, [nessa imagem](https://i.imgur.com/SBLkygZ.png) do esquerdo o interpretador de comando interpreta o simbolo `&&` como um comando. Já do lado direito da imagem o interpretador de comando não pode interpretar `&&` como um comando. 
Para que isso ocorra tem que haver uma marca indicando quando interpretar ou não os símbolos como comando o que incorre nas aspas duplas.

Comment: Tranquilo, o&& nesse bat funcio c 1 também,, @echo off &

Comment: Outra coisa, o último pode ir para a linha abaixo, funcionou aqui.. Em chamando via .cmd, ele funciona quando é parte de um segundo comando na linha: **`@echo off & 2>nul Redirect_Operator.exe <nul & && > >> < << | ||`** linha abaixo o **`<nul`**

Comment: Produz a saída **@echo off & 2>nul Redirect_Operator.exe <nul & && > >> < << | ||``**  , só remover tudo que vem antes do nome e depois do nome e o **`<nul`**  **na saída dele**, perdo te "alugar"!

Comment: Eu não sei se vai de acordo com suas expectativas, mas eu pensei em criar um comando $ para o cmd. Teria mais ou menos a sintaxe **@echo off & 2>nul $(" Redirect_Operator.exe <nul & && > >> < << | || ") **. A lógica é seguinte o que estivesse fora do **$(" ")** seria processado pelo CMD o que estivesse dentro usaria a quebra de argumento do fakeshell.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93530/discussion-between-it-wasnt-me-and-augusto-vasques).

Answer (score 4):

Passe os argumentos encadeiados com "". Desta maneira, o Console não vai interpretar o que está dentro do conjunto de caracteres.

> `echo olá >> mundo`
>
> O comando acima irá criar um arquivo "mundo" com o conteúdo "olá".
>
> `echo "olá >> mundo"`
>
> O comando acima irá imprimir `olá >> mundo` na tela.

Para isso, quando for chamar algum processo, utilize:

```
ProcessStartInfo CmdProcess = new ProcessStartInfo();
CmdProcess.Filename = "cmd.exe";
CmdProcess.UseShellExecute = true;
CmdProcess.Arguments = "\"" + "foo >> bar << & &&  |  ||  <  >  >>  <<" + "\"";

Process.Start(CmdProcess);
```

Desta forma, tudo que é passado dentro de **"..."**, é intepretado de forma literal.

> **Observação:** você divide argumentos passados para o CMD por um espaço. Como dentro de um **"..."** espaços são considerados o mesmo argumento, separe argumentos com outros campos: `cmd.exe "arg 1" "arg >> 2" "arg & 3"`

Answer (score 3):

O Prompt de Comando do Windows, por nativo, irá operar todos os caracteres que não estiverem escapados ou enclasurados em **"..."**. O que resta fazer é: **criar o seu próprio CMD**.

Escrevi um código que, tem a mesma função do Prompt de Comando do Windows e roda os mesmos comandos do mesmo, mas, **não trata operadores**. Não é necessário escapar ou enclasurar caracteres, este pequeno aplicativo não vai lidar com eles:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CustomCMD
{
    class Program
    {
        public const char ESCAPE_CHAR = '^';
        public const char ARGUMENT_DIVISOR = ' ';
        static string ContainsStringArray(string str, params string[] items)
        {
            foreach(string item in items)
            {
                if(str.Contains(item))
                {
                    return item;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        static string EvaluateCommand(string program, params string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo inf = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            inf.FileName = "CMD";
            List<string> argsParsed = new List<string>();
            foreach(string arg in args)
            {
                argsParsed.Add(PrepareArgument(arg));
            }
            inf.Arguments = "/C " + program + ARGUMENT_DIVISOR + (args.Count() == 0 ? "" : string.Join(ARGUMENT_DIVISOR.ToString(), argsParsed).Trim());
            inf.UseShellExecute = false;
            inf.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process pro = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(inf);
                pro.WaitForExit();
                Console.WriteLine(pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
            return "";
        }
        static string PrepareArgument(string argument)
        {
            // Caracteres não aceitos: &  &&  |  ||  <  >  >> e <<
            string[] notAcceptedChars = { "&", "|", "<", ">" };
            StringBuilder newArgument = new StringBuilder();
            argument = argument.Trim('"'); // remove os "" dos argumentos
            for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < argument.Length; charIndex++)
            {
                char ch = argument[charIndex];
                string extracted = ContainsStringArray(ch.ToString(), notAcceptedChars);
                if (extracted != null)
                {
                    // detectou um caractere não aceito
                    // verifica se já não está escapado
                    bool escaped = false;
                    try
                    {
                        escaped = argument[charIndex - 1] == ESCAPE_CHAR;
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { } finally
                    {
                        // início da string
                        if (!escaped) newArgument.Append(ESCAPE_CHAR);
                        newArgument.Append(ch);
                    }
                } else
                {
                    newArgument.Append(ch);
                }
            }
            string ret = argument.Trim().Contains(ARGUMENT_DIVISOR) ? '"' + newArgument.ToString() + '"' : newArgument.ToString();
            return ret ;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if(args.Count() == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Console Não Operador");
                Console.WriteLine("Criado por Gabriel Scatolin");
                Console.WriteLine();
                while(true)
                {
                    Console.Write(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "> ");
                    string input = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (input == "") continue;

                    string exe = "";
                    string[] cmdArgs = { };

                    if(input.Contains(ARGUMENT_DIVISOR) == false)
                    {
                        exe = input;
                    } else
                    {
                        string[] inputData = input.Split(ARGUMENT_DIVISOR);
                        exe = inputData[0]; ;
                        cmdArgs = inputData.Skip(1).ToArray();
                    }

                    string ev = EvaluateCommand(exe, cmdArgs);
                    if(ev != "")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Comando inválido ou arquivo não encontrado: " + ev);
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                List<string> formattedArg = new List<string>();
                foreach(string arg in args.Skip(1))
                {
                    formattedArg.Add(arg);
                }

                string ev = EvaluateCommand(args[0], formattedArg.ToArray());
                if (ev != "")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Comando inválido ou arquivo não encontrado: " + ev);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Observações importantes

- Comandos como `CD`, `CLEAR` ou `HELP` não funcionarão, uma vez que o Console está funcionando em outra sessão, diferente de cada processo invocado.
- O Console não é totalmente compatível com todos os comandos do Prompt de Comando, pois em cada comando, é invocado um comando no CMD nativo na seguinte expressão:

`CMD /C <arg0> [<arg1 formatado> <arg2 formatado> <arg3 formatado> ...]`

- Em vista disso, o aplicativo se comporta bem ao chamar métodos como `ECHO Olá&Mundo`, ou aplicativos com expressões complexas.
- Para chamar os executáveis diretamente pelos seus nomes, sem usar o CMD como porta, edite `inf.FileName = "CMD";` para `inf.FileName = program;` e edite a seguinte linha:

```cs
// de:
inf.Arguments = "/C " + program + ARGUMENT_DIVISOR + (args.Count() == 0 ? "" : string.Join(ARGUMENT_DIVISOR.ToString(), argsParsed).Trim());

// para:
inf.Arguments = args.Count() == 0 ? "" : string.Join(ARGUMENT_DIVISOR.ToString(), argsParsed).Trim();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Explicação dos métodos

- `PrepareArgument(string)` - escapa os caracteres de forma inteligente e prepara um argumento único para seu uso;
- `EvaluateCommand(string, string[])` - executa o executável, usando uma instância de Console, com os argumentos. Observação: os argumentos são formatados dentro do método, não há necessidade de formatar a entrada;
- `Main(string[])` - método de entrada dos argumentos originais.

Este sistema também consegue lidar com inicializações sem argumentos, funcionando como um terminal interativo.

Comment: vou testar amanhã, mas ja agradeço, outra coisa,vc q pagou sua outra resposta? Já pontuada (== útil p alguns operadores), não entendi do por quê não mantê-la.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe não acho ético duas respostas do mesmo autor, considerando uma delas sendo *errada* para a pergunta. Mas vou ouvir seu conselho e vou restaurar ela =)

Comment: bom dia, n funcionou, usando em bat ele trava,  fico dando n enter e ele n sai sem fechar a janela.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe você precisará implementar uma maneira de atribuir a sessão do Console para o batch. Este código que coloquei é um exemplo do que pode ser feito.

Comment: Vou insistir no seu código, obrigado, inclusive editando, no que posso.. obrigado.